# Match multiple dates in between two date columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two columns, column 1 and column 2. I want to match any date that falls between those two dates with my query.

For example:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('27-02-2017'), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime('02-03-2017'.'+1 day'));
foreach ($period as $key => $date) {    
           $data=$date->format("d-m-Y");
            //Query SELECT * FROM booking WHERE userid='67' AND ('$data' BETWEEN bookingfrom AND bookingtill)  AND service='test' AND status='0'
}
```

Period return this:

```
DatePeriod Object
(
    [start] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2017-02-24 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [current] => 
    [end] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-03 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [interval] => DateInterval Object
        (
            [y] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [d] => 1
            [h] => 0
            [i] => 0
            [s] => 0
            [weekday] => 0
            [weekday_behavior] => 0
            [first_last_day_of] => 0
            [invert] => 0
            [days] => 
            [special_type] => 0
            [special_amount] => 0
            [have_weekday_relative] => 0
            [have_special_relative] => 0
        )

    [recurrences] => 1
    [include_start_date] => 1
)
```

---

### **EDIT: Found a solution:**

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE userid='67' AND (STR_TO_DATE(`bookingfrom`, '%d-%m-%Y') <='2017-02-24' AND (STR_TO_DATE(`bookingtill`, '%d-%m-%Y') >='2017-02-24')) AND service='test' AND status='0'
```

Comment: what is $data ?

Comment: @sumit date coming from loop like 27-02-2017

Comment: shouldn't the dates be in quotes ?

Comment: when you use between clause there should be two date values not two columns.

Comment: @Suchitkumar i need to check between to columns date..if you have any idea.please place a answer

Comment: @Gulshan: this question was rolled back in a fashion that excluded a lot of updates and removed useful information. I regard that rollback as somewhat destructive, so I have rolled back to a later version. Please try to leave your questions in the best state possible, so that future readers can learn from them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE userid='67' AND bookingfrom <= $data AND bookingtill >= $data AND service='test' AND status='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that bookingfrom AND bookingtill are DATE fields:

```
SELECT * 
FROM booking 
WHERE userid='67' 
AND '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))."' BETWEEN bookingfrom AND bookingtill
AND service='test'
AND status='0'
```

With "`date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))`" you set the format to make comparison in MySql.

Comment: done. Inserted an explanation. Please remove the downvote

Comment: you have  to do  date conversion on both end .. see OP's edit

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM booking
    WHERE userid='67' AND $data >= bookingfrom
    AND $data <=bookingtill AND service='test' AND status='0'
```

Comment: You missed an AND: `userid='67' $data`

Comment: I have updated the answer. i was more focused on how to  select  the data on the bases of two date ranges, but this will solve your problem.